# Google Cloud Messaging: Do not work post network change Unless Full Restart of App

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have been troubled by the GCM for a couple of days already.
The GCM works fine in my app but when there is network change, say from wifi=>offline=>wifi or 3G=>offline=>3G, then GCM will no longer work unless I kill the app and restart the app again.

I send heartbeat to google server on a frequent basis.
I have tried FCM but the issue remains.
I need the GCM to deliver on real-time basis.
I know there are 3rd party cloud provider but i won't consider using them in the mean time.
If you have encountered similar cases and you have solved it, it will be great if you would provide solution here. Thanks in advance!!

```
 public GcmKeepAlive(Context context) {
 mContext = context;
 gTalkHeartBeatIntent = new Intent("com.google.client.android.intent.action.GTALK_HEARTBEAT");
mcsHeartBeatIntent = new Intent("com.google.client.android.intent.action.MCS_HEARTBEAT");  
}

public void broadcastIntents() {
mContext.sendBroadcast(gTalkHeartBeatIntent);
mContext.sendBroadcast(mcsHeartBeatIntent);
}
```

Comment: what version of GCM are you using?

Comment: Hi @ArthurThompson: How would i know? I just tried the latest FCM but it doesn't work. 
The problem is obvious in old device (launched 3-4 yrs ago), but the newer devices (launched 1-2 yrs ago) do not have this problem.

Comment: Do the old devices have Google Play services? What Android version are they running?